# Define F : Z → Z by the rule F(n) = 2 -3n, for all integers n

Tags: definition

I am not sure how to go about solving this problem.  Can somebody tell me how to define $F : Z \to Z$ by the rule $F(n) = 2 -3n$, for all integers  $n$ ?

I am not sure where to even start or what is meant by the question.  The assignment continues:

i)  Is $F$ one-to-one? (Prove or give a counterexample.)

ii) Is $F$ onto? (Prove or give a counterexample.)

Any help that points me in the right direction to go about solving such a problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ""Define $F$ by..." is not an instruction for you to do anything, it is just telling you what $F$ is.  You then have to answer (i) and (ii).

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense.  Do you know what "one-to-one" and "onto" means?  I am assuming one-to-one means that the value n remains the same once it passes through the function?  I am not sure what onto means.

Comment: I am $99.94$% certain that these terms will have been defined in your lectures/course/book/whatever.  Please look them up.  If not, they are certainly known to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) $F$ is one to one. We want to show from $F(a)=F(b)$ we can conclude $a=b$. I will let you see if you can conclude this part.  ii) F is not surjective. Counterexample: 0 is an integer but $2-3n \neq 0$ for any integer $n$. Summary: Basically for i) for one-to-one: we want to show there is no element in the codomain that gets hit more than once. ii) for onto: for this we want to show every element of the codomain gets hit at least once

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a lot!  How can I tell by the equation F(n) = 2-3n whether or not an element is hit?

Comment: Well f(x)=2-3x with codomain and domain all real numbers is just a line. You can look at a visual representation of your graph by erasing a lot of this line.

Comment: Say. $m$ and $n$ are integers and suppose $2-3n=m$ Then $n=\frac{2-m}{3}$. This is a contradiction because $n$ is rational here. Or I should say I guess $n=\frac{2-m}{3}$ isn't an integer for all integer $m$.

Comment: As we see  m=0 doesn't get hit because n is 2/3 then... Or m=1 doesn't get hit because n=1/3 then. m=2 does get hit because n=0 then.